# form.submit triggers onsubmit but does not submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The form

```
<form onsubmit="OnSubmitForm();" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" name="register_form" id="register_form">
```

The submit button

```
<input id="register_submit" name="submit" class="medium" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.pressed=this.value"/>
```

The submit link

```
<a href="javascript: Submit();">full registration</a>
```

The Javascript/jQuery

```
function OnSubmitForm()
{
  if(document.pressed == 'Full registration')
  {
      alert('full');
    document.register_form.action ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>account/register";
  }
  else
  if(document.pressed == 'Submit')
  {
      alert('light');
   document.register_form.action ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>account/register_light";
  }
}

function Submit()
{
    document.pressed = 'Full registration';

    $('#register_form').submit();
}
```

If the submit button is klicked the "light" alert is triggered and and the form is submitted to "account/register_light" as it should.

But if the link is klicked the "full" alert is triggered but the form is not submited. More klicks on the link does not trigger the alert nor submit the form.

If the submit buton is klicked after the link has been klicked the form is submited to "account/register"(no alert). Whitch is where i want the link to submit the form and not where de submit button usually submits the form.

Why doesn't .submit() submit the form?
I am confused here, any insight to what is happening wuld be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should really look into using jQuery to bind your event handlers. Inline event handler declarations (`onsubmit`,`onclick`,etc) and, even worse, using javascript in the `href` attribute of an anchor is horrendously outdated, and merges both content and functionality.

Comment: just in case my answer below doesn't work, you may want to alert out the `document.register_form.action` before the end of the function to see what it actually contains. (Just to double check it is what you expect.

Comment: Also I believe inline javascript is depricated by W3C not in HTML but in plain XML, I may be wrong but im pretty sure its still supported in HTML (maybe not 5) but not in XHTML (this suggests only using external scripts).  I'm not a web developer just software so I may have missed something with regard to inline javascript, but as far as I know there is nothing wrong with using inline javascript in HTML.

Comment: Ah, my bad I had misread your question :).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I did not use jQuery originally. I was just seeing if i got a different result from document.register_form.submit(). I'll clean it up as soon as i know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had misread your question for my first answer.

Anyway, the reason your form is not being submitted, or at least not the way you expect is that as far as I am aware browsers do not fire the `onsubmit` method unless the submit is invoked by the user.  Using `.submit()` will not cause it to fire.

A workaround (hopefully this should work) is to change your Submit function to the following.

```
function Submit()
{
    document.pressed = 'Full registration';
    OnSubmitForm();
    $('#register_form').submit();
}
```

I am also unsure about setting `document.pressed`, you may not be able to do this.  If not then you could always pass a parameter to the OnSubmitForm function.

Comment: Does not help (tested). My problem is that the form is not actually submited. The OnSubmitForm() does trigger (at least the first time i press the link). With your change it is called twice. (the documetn.pressed gets set)

Comment: Then I am as confused as you are.  Is there any other code that could potentially be interfering? I can't see that there would be but it's a longshot.

Comment: I have some validation code, but i tried with commenting it away. Did not change anything (exept removing the validation).